# Quick Regex Inquiry: How to check for * or + at the start or end of a string?

Tags: regex

```
"*,10,10,+,+,20,*,3+"
```

I am trying to catch a * or + at the start or end of a string. I tried the following

```
/^(\+|\*)/ 
/(\+|\*)$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ...and what happened when you tried it? What language/environment are you using? What string are you testing against?

Answer (score 0):

Use alternation operator or OR operator which is `|` to combine both. Also, you  need to to escape the characters `*` and `+` as they have a special meaning.

To escape escaping, you can just put them in a character class so they are treated as just literals.

```
^[*+]|[*+]$
```